# Hyperion Retrieve for Excel - Citrix Environment Profile Corruption

Tags: terminal, profile, citrix, corrupt, hyperion

We have an intermittent issue where sometimes when users are trying to access Hyperion Retrieve for Excel, via Citrix, they are not being prompted to provide credentials upon opening the application. We can tell that the authentication process is being overlooked because the data is not able to be viewed. Once we delete the user's profile that is created on the Terminal Server, the problem is resolved once the user launches the application again via Citrix (A new windows profile is created on the TS). I am unable to pinpoint the root cause of these user's profiles becoming "corrupted". Any suggestions here?

Environment:
citrix Xenapp 6.5
Windows Server 2008 R2
Roaming Profiles option is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Timezone Redirection Policy has successfully resolved this issue.